# Jetpack workmanager doesn't return success

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am using android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:1.0.0-alpha11 and have bumped into an issue on Samsung Galaxy S8+ running Android 7.0. With other devices it works fine.

```
    val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build()
    val inputData: Data = Data.Builder()
            .putString(INPUT_DATA_FRONT_URI, front?.toString())
            .putString(INPUT_DATA_BACK_URI, back?.toString())
            .build()
    val work = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<LicenseUploadWorker>()
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .setInputData(inputData)
            .build()
    workManager.beginUniqueWork(LICENSE_UPLOAD_WORKER, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, work)
            .enqueue()
```

Work is scheduled and executed successfully, however the LiveData i get from here

```
workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(work.id)
```

never gets the `WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED` state update. From the logs I can see that the work completes without any issues:

```
11-26 12:12:03.693 6820 6852 I WorkerWrapper: Worker result SUCCESS for Work
```

Is there a way around this issue for now?

Comment: How are you observing the LiveData returned by WorkManager? there's an example in the WorkManager's Codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager-kt/#7

Answer (score 1):

you can observe the status by subscribing directly to the return value of `enqueue()`, e.g.:

```
val workOperation = workManager.beginUniqueWork(LICENSE_UPLOAD_WORKER, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, work).enqueue()

workOperation.state.observe(this, Observer { state ->
     Timber.d("state: $state")
})
```

Comment: I needed the state pretty far away form all the lifecycleOwners (the UI), but I still ended up implementing workaround using the LiveData.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue during the development cycle of my app (on a different device). The solution for me was to simply uninstall my app. The next time I launched it from Android Studio everything worked.